# My avocado pit split in two

Tags: diseases, avocado, rot, blight

My avocado plant has been growing really well and it's healthy. One problem is that the pit it sprouted from has started getting kinda black and I touched it a bit too hard and it fell off. Also I think i've got blight on my avocado because some of the tips of the leaves are brown.
My question is - is it a problem that the pit is no longer attached to the plant and how do I treat the disease(I am not sure if it is blight)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The pit part is a duplicate: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63514/6806 and there's no point leaving the broken off part of the pit with the plant once it's broken off.

Answer (score 3):

Once the plant is well established, the pit falling off should not matter.

As to the brown spots on the leaves, round up the usual suspects.

- Clean up any litter in the pot and clip off any clearly dead leaves. This will reduce the possibility of fungus.
- The correct water schedule is important. Different varieties will prefer different degrees of wetness in the soil. You may need to experiment.
- The right amount of light is important. Same advice as previous.
- Many plants do poorly near heating or A/C. I don't see such in your photos, just mention it for completeness. The air flow tends to dry out the leaves.
- Inspect for insects. You might need a small magifying glass. If there are insects, you need an insecticide that is safe for you and the plant. I don't know how avacados will react to insecticidal soap, but it's safe for you. Check with your local garden shop for some possibilities.
- The right sized pot is important. Some varieties will want to be "root bound." Others will want more space.
- The right kind of soil and fertilizer is important. Check with your local garden center for suggestions as to ferilizer that is safe for an avacado.

Answer (score 0):

Avocado is a dicotyledon plant as compared to a monocotyledon.  Meaning it has two seed leaves.  They are the first leaves of the plant.  Once it starts growing other leaves, these are discarded.

[More Information at study.com](https://study.com/learn/lesson/dicotyledon-plants-concept-examples-dicot-plants.html)

I would leave them alone unless they are well and truly detached.

[image: Monocot Vs Dicot]